# Customize React Big Calendar colors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-big-calendar

I am new to React Big Calendar and it seems very useful but I'm stuck. I am creating a dark mode web site the default buttons work for what I want but the text is black and doesn't show up well on a dark background. Is there a way to not create a custom toolbar but to only change the text color (active button, hover button, and non active button text colors) ?  I have seen custom toolbars but that seems like over kill to just change the text color of the default buttons.

thanks for the help.

I am using 
React 
Typescript 
of course React Big Calendar

Answer (score 0):

If you use sass you can change a range of variables which should give you what you require.

```css
@import 'react-big-calendar/lib/sass/styles';

$out-of-range-color: lighten(#333, 40%);
$out-of-range-bg-color: lighten(#333, 70%);

$calendar-border: #DDD;
$cell-border: #DDD;

$border-color: #CCC;

$segment-width: percentage(1 / 7);

$time-selection-color: white;
$time-selection-bg-color: rgba(0,0,0, .50);
$date-selection-bg-color: rgba(0,0,0, .10);


$event-bg: #3174ad;
$event-border: darken(#3174ad, 10%);
$event-outline: #3b99fc;
$event-color: #fff;
$event-border-radius: 5px;
$event-padding: 2px 5px;
$event-zindex: 4;

$btn-color: #373a3c;
$btn-bg: #fff;
$btn-border: #ccc;

$current-time-color: #74ad31;

$rbc-css-prefix: rbc-i;

$today-highlight-bg: #eaf6ff;
```